# WebApi2 IHttpActionResult strongly typed return values

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponse

It is possible and not ideal to do this: (a vastly simplified example!)

```
[Serializable]
public class MyRecord
{
    public string key {get; set;}
    public string data {get; set;}
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string SomeKey)
{
    if(ExistsInDB(SomeKey))
    {
        return Ok(SomeRecordFromDB(SomeKey));  //SomeRecord() returns a POCO MyRecord.
    }
    else
    {
        //I know I can return NotFound() but not the focus of my Q
        return Ok(false);  //returns "False"
    }
}
```

Effectively demonstrating no compile time error checking on the return type.  This example will return either a JSon serialized POCO class (JSon is set on my accept header) or it will return the text "False" which puts the burden of type checking on the client.

I wouldn't do this by design but my team is refactoring a **lot** of code from asmx/svc and mistakes creep in.  I like it when the compiler helps to trap these kinds of errors rather than waiting for module or unit testing.

Is the right way to go back to using strongly typed method signatures (avoiding the IHttpActionResult and the Ok(), NotFound(), etc helpers or is there something like a  `IHttpActionResult<T>` that can be used to make sure the right type is being returned?

M.

Comment: I think you are over thinking this. You don't need to return strongly typed return values. In fact it's actually a blessing that is doesn't matter. This is vastly based on the fact that your transport schema, be it XML or JSON doesn't care about a type. What happens when your method needs to return something else, all that changing of types for no reason. After building a lot of web apps, this part should be seriously the last thing you need to be thinking about.

Comment: I see how this approach can work in many situations and the flexibility of WebAPI has been great during development.  In my situation, this is more where API in WebAPI is now more about a contract with the consumer and what they will get in response to a request rather than a convenient transport mechanism (still true).  Regarding what happens when a method needs to return something else...we would consider that a breaking change to the contract and act accordingly to ensure both ends of the contract can adopt the change.  Not disputing what you say here is appropriate for many situations.

Comment: Yeah, I still think you're over thinking it. The api action is the end goal, as long as your data up until that point is correct, you should not be typing you results!! What you should be doing is creating integration tests to assert that your api is generating the correct data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is a good practice to return `IHttpActionResult`, indicating the corresponding `http status`. Something like:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string SomeKey)
{
    if(ExistsInDB(SomeKey))
        return Ok(SomeRecordFromDB(SomeKey));

    return NotFound();
}
```

But if you really want to have a strongly typed api, you can do something like:

```
 public async Task<StronglyTypeResponse> Get()
 {
     return new StronglyTypeResponse();
 }
```

Or, create a typed response, and you'll keep the http status code, etc in your response:

```
public class StronglyTypeResponse
{

}

public class StronglyTypedResult<T> : IHttpActionResult
{
    HttpConfiguration _configuration;
    T _content;
    HttpStatusCode _statusCode;
    HttpRequestMessage _request;

    public StronglyTypedResult(T content, HttpStatusCode statusCode, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _content = content;
        _request = request;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(_statusCode)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<dynamic>(_content, _configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter),
            RequestMessage = _request,
            ReasonPhrase = "some phrase"
        };

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

And then you can create your method:

```
public async Task<StronglyTypedResult<StronglyTypeResponse>> Get()
{
    return new StronglyTypedResult<StronglyTypeResponse>(new StronglyTypeResponse(), HttpStatusCode.OK, Request, Configuration);
}
```

#### Creating your own custom generic IHttpActionResult

It's basically the same:

```
public class IHttpActionResult<T> : System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult
{
    HttpConfiguration _configuration;
    T _content;
    HttpStatusCode _statusCode;
    HttpRequestMessage _request;

    public IHttpActionResult(T content, HttpStatusCode statusCode, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _content = content;
        _request = request;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(_statusCode)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<dynamic>(_content, _configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter),
            RequestMessage = _request,
            ReasonPhrase = "some phrase"
        };

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

And now you can return the class you want with a typed `IHttpActionResult`:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult<YourClass>> Get()
{
    var yourclass = new YourClass();

    return new IHttpActionResult<YourClass>(yourclass, HttpStatusCode.OK, Request, Configuration);
}
```

Comment: I think this would go a long way to formalizing the contact.  I wonder if I could call StronglyTypedResult<T> IHttpActionResult<T>?  I'll try it.  One other brain-dead simple way I thought about was just to have a very thin WebAPI method and all the type checking is done in a .net method.  So have a method called private MyRecord Get().  The amount of unchecked typing would be the one line withing the WebAPI.  Return Ok(Get(SomeKey));

Comment: But StronglyTypedResult<T> is a IHttpActionResult<T>. You can even call StronglyTypedResult IHttpActionResult if you want, I'll edit the answer to show you.

Comment: yep - on same page.  Was talking about calling it IHttpActionResult<T>. that so it communicates that it does the same thing (and offers the same helpers) but adds type.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I assume this happened from simplifying/editing here, but I suspect you don't really want to name a class implementation `IAnything` (as the naming convention is pretty strongly associated with interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using strongly typed method signatures is that there is no way for you to return an "error" object if something is wrong with the request, be it validation errors or not found errors.

So if you want to use strongly typed signatures then you either have to included some sort of "error" object reference in your return type or explicitly throw exceptions..

The good thing about using **HttpActionResult** is that you are not constrained to a specific return type. So you could, for example, return **OK(someObject)** or **BadRequest(errorObject)**. However, it is up to the developer to write the method correctly and double check that nothing happens like the example you mentioned above.

Comment: I think Slava's response helps with that situation albeit at the cost of wrapping up your real types.  I agree with the flexibility httpactionresult offers. In a large refactor project like this, the aim was to try to reduce errors at compile time.  I think I have a simple approach that may help my situation.  Appreciate yours and others perspective on the flexibility side of WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code this way:

```
public class Answer<T>
{
    public T result {get;set;}
    public bool success {get;set;}
    public string exception {get;set;}
}

public async Task<Answer<MyRecord>> Get(string SomeKey)
{
    var answer = new Answer<MyRecord>();
    try
    {     
        if(ExistsInDB(SomeKey))
        {
            answer.result = await SomeRecordFromDB(SomeKey);
            answer.success = true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        answer.exception = e.Message;            
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: what about errors - how to return errors that occur server side  ?

Comment: Ok, so you don't want to throw an error.. you are still returning a 200-OK.. I'd prefer for the webapi to return something like 4xx or 5xx series http error and the client-side library to fall into the .catch() portion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ObjectResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    object _value;
    HttpRequestMessage _request;

    public ObjectResult(object value, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        _value = value;
        _request = request;
    }


    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_value == null)
            return Task.FromResult(_request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

        var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _value);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}

   //create your method:

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return new ObjectResult(repository.GetAll(), Request);
    }
```